# JDBC can't establish connection with SQL, nullPointerException error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans, jframe

Cannot establish connection with SQL, when run it gives nullpointerexception error

the table should display the data, but instead it shows nothing since jdbc doesn't connect to SQL

here's the class to connect it to SQL

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLDataException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Koneksi {

    private static Connection MySQLConfig;
    static Connection con;
    static Statement stm;

    private static Connection config() throws SQLDataException, SQLException {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/latihandatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "";
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            MySQLConfig = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            System.out.println("Koneksi Berhasil: ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("koneksi gagal" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return MySQLConfig;
    }
}
```

and here's the JFrame class

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class form_buku extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public form_buku() {
        initComponents();
        kosongkanForm();
        TampilData();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable3 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Batal");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

        jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

        jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

        jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Form buku");

        jButton2.setText("Tambah Data");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Edit");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Hapus");

        jButton6.setText("Simpan");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("Keluar");

        jLabel2.setText("ID Buku");

        jLabel3.setText("Judul Buku");

        jLabel4.setText("Pengarang");

        jLabel5.setText("Harga");

        jLabel6.setText("Stock");

        jTable3.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTable3);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 110, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jButton3)
                                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                                .addComponent(jButton5)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jButton6)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                                .addComponent(jButton7)))))
                .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton5)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton7))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        kosongkanForm();
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                        

    public void kosongkanForm() {
        jTextField1.setText(null);
        jTextField2.setText(null);
        jTextField3.setText(null);
        jTextField4.setText(null);
        jTextField5.setText(null);
    }

private void TampilData(){
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.addColumn("ID");
    model.addColumn("Judul");
    model.addColumn("Pengarang");
    model.addColumn("Harga");
    model.addColumn("Stock");

    try{

        String sql = "SELECT * from BUKU";
        Koneksi.stm=Koneksi.con.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet res=Koneksi.stm.executeQuery(sql);

        while(res.next()){
            model.addRow(new Object[]{
            res.getString(1),
            res.getString(2),
            res.getString(3),
            res.getString(4),
            res.getString(5)});
        }
        jTable3.setModel(model);
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());

    }
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form_buku.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form_buku.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form_buku.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form_buku.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new form_buku().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

when it was run it gives out this error

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at form_buku.TampilData(form_buku.java:252)
    at form_buku.<init>(form_buku.java:10)
    at form_buku$4.run(form_buku.java:298)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

i'm kinda new to this so I can't determine why it doesn't connect with SQL

Answer (score 0):

You never call `config()` anywhere. That would initialize `con`, so, without having called it, that is still `null`, and thus, `NullPointerException`.

Separately, catching an exception and just printing something is a really bad idea. If you can't handle them (and 'print something' isn't handling them).

If the checked nature is a problem, rewrap them. Go into your IDE settings right now and fix the template - it needs to be:

```
try {
 .. code ..
} catch (CheckedException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
}
```

*NOT* `e.printStackTrace()` or `System.err.println(e)` or any other such 'print it and continue' craziness.